# Run flow check continuously (flowtype)

Tags: facebook, flowtype

I was wondering if someone knew of a good way to continuously run the "flow check" command inside a given repo such that it will re-run anytime a file is updated?

Thanks!
Thomas

Comment: If you use ESLint, use [eslint-plugin-flowtype-errors](https://github.com/amilajack/eslint-plugin-flowtype-errors). It allows Flow errors to be reported as ESLint errors. It works really nicely if you already have IDE or texteditor integration for flow.

Answer (score 11):

`fswatch -o ./ | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'clear; printf "\033[3J" && flow'` using https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch will get you a nice color-coded experience that is cleared properly every time

and if you wanna put it in your NPM scripts, here's the escaped version:

`"flow-watch": "fswatch -o ./ | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'clear; printf \"\\033[3J\" && flow'"`

Comment: your comment sans `clear...` in @JeffMo 's post doesn't  flash the screen, more visually comfortable to use. Thanks for both!

Comment: This is great but I found it annoying how it would rerun flow when any type of file was changed, including vim swapfiles. I added `-e '.*' -i '\\.js$'` to restrict this to only rerun on JavaScript changes.

Answer (score 7):

I like to use the `watch` command while dev-ing a Flpw codebase: `watch -t npm run flow`

It's available on most Linux distress by default, and you can `brew install watch` on Mac. I'm sure there's a Windows equivalent too?

Comment: `watch -n 0.5 -d npm run flow | head -30` is what I personally use, haven't been able to make that use color though...

Comment: @JeffMo do you know how to preserve the color coding though? for me, the results all come out one color. it works nicely though.

Comment: well this does it: `fswatch -o ./ | xargs -n1 -I{} flow` fswatch supports colorization on macs whereas watch does not: https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch I've tried doing `clear; printf '\033[3J' && flow` and other such combinations to clear the screen in between updates but i cant get it to work. What I'm trying to do is make it so i dont have a long list of errors where I cant find where the most recent errors started. If anyone knows how to clear let me know.

Comment: here it is: fswatch -o ./ | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'clear; printf "\033[3J" && flow'

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flow-bro`'s watch command, [see here](https://github.com/DanielMSchmidt/flow-bro#watch-alias-w).

Answer (score 1):

This `gulp` task using [`gulp-flowtype`](https://github.com/charliedowler/gulp-flowtype) should do it:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var flow = require('gulp-flowtype')

gulp.task('watch', function() {

    // set up a watcher
  gulp.watch('*.js', function (file) {
      return gulp.src(file.path)
        .pipe(flow())
    })
})
```